# QLabel en diferente hilo

Tags: python, hilos, pyqt5

En el siguiente código utilizo firebase para conectarme a la base datos y mi intención es que mientras ese proceso ocurre un `QLabel` muestre el texto Cargando por ejemplo para lo cual lo hice algo así:

```
t = threading.Thread(target=self.lable.setText("cargando")).start()
```

pero no funciona, el texto se muestra hasta que termina de cargar la información la función:

en este codigo agrege las corecciones que me señalaron, mediante un QComboBox detono el hilo para que actualice el texto del qlabel y dentro de la clase worker el metodo iniciar_conexion detona lo que se realizara utilizando firebse

**Nuevo codigo**

```
    from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QTableWidgetItem
from FirebaseProjectLogin import *
import threading

class Worker(QtCore.QObject):
    started = QtCore.pyqtSignal()
    finished =QtCore.pyqtSignal()



    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def iniciar_conexion(self):
        self.started.emit()
        self.Tabla.setRowCount(0)

        totalMatutino = "0"


        ref = db.reference("/")
        ret = ref.get()

        for key in ret.items():

            if key[0][:7]==str(self.Fecha):
                for key1 in key[1].items():
                    if key1[0]==self.Sucursal:
                        for key2 in key1[1].items():
                            if key2[0] == "Matutino":
                                for key3 in key2[1].items():
                                    if key3[0] == "15:00":
                                        for key5 in key3[1].items():
                                            if key5[0]=="total":
                                                totalMatutino = key5[1]

                                                self.Tabla.insertRow(self.currentRow)

                                        self.Tabla.setItem(self.currentRow,5,QTableWidgetItem(totalMatutino))
```

self.finished.emit()

```
class DatosGeneralesClass():

    def __init__(self,mes,sucursal,ano,tabla,status,boton):

        self.Mes = "01"
        self.Sucursal = "Exxe 1"

        self.Ano = "2018"
        self.Tabla = tabla
        self.currentRow = self.Tabla.rowCount()
        self.Fecha = self.Ano+"-"+self.Mes
        self.Status =status

        ano.currentIndexChanged.connect(lambda:self.updateAno(ano.currentText()))

        self._worker = Worker()
        self._worker.started.connect(self.on_started)
        self.__worker.finished.connect(self.on_finished)
        thread = QtCore.QThread(self)
        self._worker.moveToThread(thread)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def on_started(self):
        self.DStatus.setText("Cargando")
    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def on_finished(self):
        self.DStatus.setText("complete")



    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(str)
    def updateAno(self,ano):

        self.Ano = ano
        self.Fecha = self.Ano+"-"+self.Mes

        self.conectar()

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def conectar(self):
        QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(0,self._worker.iniciar_conexion)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero dos observaciones:

- **No interactúes jamás directamente con un widget desde un hilo/proceso que no sea el principal**. Solo se debe interactuar con la GUI desde su propio hilo. Lo que si puedes es informar mediante métodos seguros al hilo principal desde el hilo hijo para que el primero haga los cambios necesarios en la interfaz. Una forma muy simple es usar señales.
- **Qt (y PyQt por supuesto) tiene su propio mecanismo para crear hilos, [`QThread`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html)**. Deberías usarlo en vez de los hilos nativos de Python, lo cual permite, por ejemplo, establecer una comunicación mediante señales entre los hilos de forma simple y segura.

Dicho esto, un ejemplo reproducible y simplificado de lo que deseas podría ser el siguiente:

```
import sys
import time
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets



class Worker(QtCore.QObject):
    # Señal que nos permitirá transferir información entre los hilos
    resultado = QtCore.pyqtSignal(int)

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def iniciar_conexion(self):
        self.resultado.emit(1)
        '''Función que hará el trabajo bloqueante en el hilo'''
        time.sleep(5) # Simulamos proceso bloqueante
        self.resultado.emit(-1)


class App(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle('Ejemplo QThread')
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 400, 300)

        self.boton_iniciar = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Conectar', self)
        self.boton_iniciar.move(150, 150) 
        self.boton_iniciar.clicked.connect(self.conectar)

        self.label_estado = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.label_estado.setGeometry(160, 80,  400, 50)
        self.label_estado.setText('Sin conectar')

        self._thread = None
        self._worker = None



    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def conectar(self):
        """
        Slot encargado de lanzar el hilo
        """
        self.boton_iniciar.setEnabled(False)
        # Instanciamos un QThread
        self._thread = QtCore.QThread()
        # Instanciamos nuestra clase worker
        self._worker = Worker()
        self._thread.started.connect(self._worker.iniciar_conexion)
        # Movemos el worquer al hilo
        self._worker.moveToThread(self._thread)
        # Conectamos la señal del worker con un slot encargado de actualizar la gui
        self._worker.resultado.connect(self._estado)
        self._thread.start() 


    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(int)
    def _estado(self, res):
        if res == 1:  # Conexión en proceso
            self.label_estado.setText("Conectando...")
            return

        elif res == 0:    # Conexión exitosa
            self.label_estado.setText("Conexión completada")
            self._thread.quit()
            self._thread.wait()

        else:           # Conexión fallida
            self.label_estado.setText("Conexión fallida")
            self.boton_iniciar.setText("Reintentar")
            self.boton_iniciar.setEnabled(True)

        self._thread.quit()
        self._thread.wait()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ventana = App()
    ventana.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Tu respuesta es válida pero solo una observación a tu comentario: *Qt (y PyQt por supuesto) tiene su propio mecanismo para crear hilos, QThread. Deberías usarlo en vez de los hilos nativos de Python*, Qt no crea nuevos tipos de hilos, QThread no es un hilo, es un manejador de los hilos nativos de la OS de manera similar a lo que hace el modulo threading. En conclusión los hilos nativos de python son los mismo hilos nativos que usa Qt, es decir ambos manejan los hilos nativos de la OS. IMHO yo suelo combinar el uso entre uno u otro dependiendo del contexto.

Comment: @FJSevilla, estaba funcionando bien pero de rrepente salio esto: TypeError: connect() failed between Worker.resultado[int] and _estado()

Comment: Hola @AngelJudathAlvarez, ¿esto te pasa con mi código tal como está  o al modificarlo para ajustarlo a tu caso? Si es este segundo caso, edita tu pregunta si quieres y al final de la misma (dejando lo que ya tienes) agrega la parte relevante del código.

Comment: @FJSevilla, funciono perfecto gracias, una pregunta mas si quisera enviar un widget de la clase App a la clase worker de de enviarlo al momento de instaciar la clase worker y dentro la clase worker definirlos en el metodo init `def__init__(self,widget)`

Comment: @AngelJudathAlvarez por poder puedes pero recuerda que desde el hilo no debes nunca modificar el widget ni nada de la interfaz, debe ser el hilo principal el que haga esto siempre. Puedes usar las señales que quieras y del tipo que necesites para pasar información entre ambos, pero no intentes interactuar con el widget desde el hilo.

Answer (score 1):

No voy a repetir lo que señala válidamente @FJSevilla, salvo ciertas observaciones. Mi respuesta va en reestructurar la respuesta de @FJSevilla para que sea más versatil el manejo de los hilos. Por ejemplo en la siguiente implementación no uso la señal started de QThread para iniciar el proceso, el hilo ya esta iniciado, y para invocar al slot del worker solo uso un `QTimer.singleShot(0, ...)`. Ademas para indicar el inicio y el final del proceso he creado 2 señales para que sea más verboso.

```py
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, uic
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import db,credentials


class Worker(QtCore.QObject):
    started = QtCore.pyqtSignal()
    finished = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def iniciar_conexion(self):
        self.started.emit()
        cred = credentials.Certificate("accesFire.json")
        firebase_admin.initialize_app(
            cred, {"databaseURL": "https://exe-tablas.firebaseio.com/"}
        )
        ref = db.reference("/")
        ret = ref.get()
        # other task
        self.finished.emit()


class App(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        uic.loadUi("prubea.ui",self)
        self.comboBox.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.connect)

        self._worker = Worker()
        self._worker.started.connect(self.on_started)
        self._worker.finished.connect(self.on_finished)
        thread = QtCore.QThread(self)
        thread.start()
        self._worker.moveToThread(thread)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def on_started(self):
        self.label.setText("cargando")

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def on_finished(self):
        self.label.setText("cargado")

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(int)
    def conectar(self, index):
        if index == 4:
            QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(0, self._worker.iniciar_conexion)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ventana = App()
    ventana.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: me ayudo a entender un poco mejor el concepto sin embargo como le mencione a @FJSevilla, me lanza un error `TypeError: connect() failed between Worker.resultado[int] and _estado() `

Comment: @AngelJudathAlvarez ese error no tiene nada que ver con mi codigo

Comment: probe de nuevo con tu codigo pero me sale un error muy similar `connect() failed between Worker.started[] and on_started()` a no ser que me haya equivocado en algo. Te agaradezco de antemano por tu pasiensia

Comment: @AngelJudathAlvarez ¿has copiado mi codigo tal como esta?, yo no he usado `[]`: `self._worker.started.connect(self.on_started)`. Yo no sé de donde sacaste los `[]`

Comment: asi es de hecho modifique el codigo de arriba ese es el que estoy usando

Comment: @AngelJudathAlvarez si usas mi codigo no tienes que usar `[]`, no me pronunciare sobre otro código que no sea el mio

Comment: pero no estoy ocuoando corchetes en ningun lado

Comment: @AngelJudathAlvarez pues el error que señalas dice lo contrario: **connect() failed between Worker.started*[]* and on_started()**

Comment: subi de nuevo el codigo para que lo veas

Comment: @AngelJudathAlvarez tu codigo esta mal identado, corrigelo

Comment: lo rescribi desde 0 y sigue con el error y si elimino la linea de `self.worker.started.connect` ahora el error se pasa a `self.worker.finished.connect`

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93027/discussion-between-angel-judath-alvarez-and-eyllanesc).